# Reducer ngrx undefined initialState

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am updating to ngrx 8, and I noticed that in the `reducer` function the type of the `state` parameter can be either `State` or `undefined`

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#creating-the-reducer-function

```
export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return scoreboardReducer(state, action);
}
```

Is there any reason for the `undefined` optional type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that it is for type checking for default parameters. To set the initialState, you can do

```
export function reducer(state: State | undefined = {}, action: Action) {
  return scoreboardReducer(state, action);
}
```

Check out the `= {}`. If `state` is undefined, it will be equal to `{}`.

You can set the `initialState` when undefined or just leave it.

Comment: But what's the point of explicitly specifying that? If it's undefined then it should be just set as undefined without the need for the `| undefined` ..?

Comment: I guess because the type can be either of `State | undefined`.

Comment: Okay, so here we are using `undefined` as a type

Comment: But `typeof undefined = 'undefined'`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

The first time that the reducers get invoked it's with an `undefined` state.
This is done, so you're able to provide a default value for the state.